# How to Open a new tab or windows from controller MVC ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I need to process something on the server from **DetailsController** from my **DetailsView** and then I need to return to the **DetailsView**, but I need display a new windows with the proceced info in new view (**DetailsPrint**) too, so, any idea how I can make this?

Note: is mandatory go to server, so

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Action", new {controller="ControllerName"}, new {target="_blank"})
```

or

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home",new { Model.ID })';return false;">Detail</button>

    <input type="button" title="Delete" value="D" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ID })'" />
```

dont work for me

Comment: How about adding in the view a `window.open` script in the post action?

Answer (score 2):

Action link must, as you correctly coded, have target = _blank to open a new window.
At the same time, a parameter must be supplied to DetailsController to let him know he must return DetailsPrint view instead of the normal DetailsView.

You can supply this parameter by query string

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Action?print=true", new {controller="ControllerName"}, new {target="_blank"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the controller action method from a simple submit Form link as

```
<input type="submit" value="Print"/>
```

then you can add a style with the style property formtarget="_blank as follows :

```
<input type="submit" value="Print" style=" formtarget="_blank"/>
```

This will show the view result from the controller in New tab .